How do I best layout a kivy project so it can be built for multiple platforms?
I'm trying to figure out a project layout for a kivy app that will allow it to be built as:

a python module (so it can be distributed via pypi and thus 'pipx install')
an android app
a windows app (via PyInstaller)
an iOS app

I'm familiar with the requirements for 1, and I'm a fan of simple, so I use the so-called 'flat' or 'ad-hoc' layout.  My files look like:
.
├── pyproject.toml
├── buildozer.spec
└── my_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── source

But my unusual main.py placement makes the android build fail.... and I haven't even gotten to PyInstaller or iOS yet.  Is there a layout that will work for all of them?

Both buildozer and pyinstaller use spec files that can indicate where the python scripts are located.

And if my app is wrapped in a python module, where do I put the main.py?

I don't think it is necessary to move your main.py, you can just use the source.dir: line in your buildozer.spec to point to the folder that contains your main.py.

My eventual answer was:

make a build.kivy directory
make a Makefile that will copy the main.py and the module source into the 'right' relative places in that directory
make a Makefile target that will call the buildozer build apk step and make it depend on step 2.

